# Magento2: Add modal popup to admin grid column using block approcah

Tags: grid, magento2.2.3, modal-popup, custom-admin-grid

There is an admin grid created in block method. Now I want to add a new column with a button or link that will open a popup when clicked. So instead of having the `edit/view` link that redirects to another page I could view the required details inside the popup on the same page. Is there any easy method to achieve this feature?
The existing columns are added in the `_prepareColumns` function as below,

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn(
        'user_id',
        [
            'header' => __('Seller ID'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'user_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'view', [
        'header' => __('Show more'),
        'type' => 'action',
        'actions' => [
            [
                'caption' => __('Show more'),
                'url' => [
                    'base' => '',
                ],
                'field' => ''
            ]
        ],
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
        'index' => 'user_id',
        'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
        'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
    ]);
    $this->addColumn(
        'seller_name',
        [
            'header' => __('Seller Name'),
            'index' => 'user_id',
            'filter' => false,
            'renderer' => 'MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\SellersGridSellerName'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'seller_state',
        [
            'header' => __('State/Province'),
            'index' => 'state',
            'type'   => 'text',
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'seller_status',
        [
            'header' => __('Seller Status'),
            'index' => 'userstatus',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => array(
                '1'=>'Active',
                '2'=>'Deactivated',
                '0'=>'Pending'
            ),
            'renderer' => 'MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\SellersGridSellerStatus'
        ]
    );
    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
    if ($block) {
        $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
    }

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Now I would like to open a popup when clicked on 'Show more' link to show more information about the seller. Please let me know if there is a way. Thank you in advance!